# display lowest level of componentID in recursion problem

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, recursion

I am working with manufacturing data, trying to explode out assemblies to their most granular component parts and quantities.  Here is some simplified sample data:

```
select *
into #assemblies
from
(
    values
    ('D', 'C', 2),
    ('C', 'B', 4),
    ('B', 'A', 3),
    ('B', 'X', 10)
) d (AssemblyID, ComponentID, Quantity);

select * from #assemblies;
```

This is saying to make one `D` assembly 2 `C` components are needed.
The `C` component is also an assembly which has to be made before `D` can be made.  To make 1 `C` assembly, 4 `B` assemblies are required.
In turn `B` is also an assembly and 3 `A` and 10 `X` components are necessary make 1 `B`.

The goal is to display how many `A` and `X` components are needed to make 1 `D`.  Here is my attempt thus far:

```
with assemblies as
(
    select Depth = 1, AssemblyID, ComponentID, NestedComponentID = ComponentID, Quantity
    from #assemblies a  --anchor member
    union all
    select Depth = a.Depth + 1, r.AssemblyID, r.ComponentID, NestedComponentID = a.ComponentID, Quantity = r.Quantity * a.Quantity
    from #assemblies r  --recursive member
    inner join assemblies a
    on r.ComponentID = a.AssemblyID
)
select * from assemblies order by AssemblyID, Depth;
```

While this query gives the correct quantities for `A` and `X` at the deepest level it does not show the correct NestedComponentIDs for `A` and `X`.
[image]

In the red rectangle I expected the ComponentID column to display `B` and the NestedComponentID column to display `A` and `X`, respectively.  How can the query be modified to achieve the intended result?

Also, this sample data is only 3 levels deep.  There are other assemblies that go deeper so the solution needs to be able to work for the deeper assemblies as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your depth the relationship between Component and NestedComponent seems very arbitrary.

My expected output would be...

```
1   B   1   B    3   A   (Assembly B is made from 1 B, which is made from  3 A)
1   B   1   B   10   X   (Assembly B is made from 1 B, which is made from 10 X)

1   C   1   C    4   B   (Assembly C is made from 1 C, which is made from  4 B)
2   C   4   B   12   A   (Assembly C is made from 4 B, which is made from 12 A)
2   C   4   B   40   X   (Assembly C is made from 4 B, which is made from 40 X)

1   D   1   D    2   C   (Assembly D is made from 1 D, which is made from  2 C)
2   D   2   C    8   B   (Assembly D is made from 2 C, which is made from  8 B)
3   D   8   B   24   A   (Assembly D is made from 8 B, which is made from 24 A)
3   D   8   B   80   X   (Assembly D is made from 8 B, which is made from 80 X)
```

Then, at every level the meaning is consistent?

*(If you agree, I'll code it.  If you disagree, please edit you question to specifically state the meaning of each field at each depth level.)*

***EDIT:*** SQL

```
WITH
  assemblyTree AS
(
  SELECT
    0                   AS Depth,
    AssemblyID          AS AssemblyID,
    1                   AS ComponentCount,
    AssemblyID          AS ComponentID,
    Quantity            AS NestedComponentCount,
    ComponentID         AS NestedComponentID 
  FROM
    #assemblies
 
  UNION ALL
  
  SELECT
    parent.Depth + 1,
    parent.AssemblyID,
    parent.NestedComponentCount,
    parent.NestedComponentID,
    parent.NestedComponentCount * Child.Quantity,
    child.ComponentID
  FROM
    assemblyTree   AS parent
  INNER JOIN
    #assemblies    AS child
      ON parent.NestedComponentID = child.AssemblyID
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  assemblyTree
ORDER BY
  AssemblyID,
  Depth,
  ComponentID,
  NestedComponentID
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=497a0eff8b581adbf9a0070f052b00d6

***NOTE:*** By getting the top level row consistent with child rows, everything becomes easy.

Comment: Yes, I agree with your expected output.

Answer (score 1):

```
;WITH assemblie_line
AS (
    SELECT  AssemblyID  , 
            ComponentID ,
            Quantity
    FROM #assemblies
    WHERE AssemblyID = 'D'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT  L.AssemblyID                ,
            A.ComponentID               ,
            L.Quantity * A.Quantity
    FROM assemblie_line L
    JOIN #assemblies A ON A.AssemblyID = L.ComponentID
)
SELECT * 
FROM assemblie_line X
WHERE X.ComponentID = 'X'
```